# How to find out why IIS application pool is recycling due to application pool property changes

Tags: iis, application-pools

My application pool is recycling when I don't want it to be (note I've already disabled the time-based & inactivity-based recycling).

I see in the event log a 5080 event:

> The worker processes serving application pool '%1' are being recycled due to 1 or more configuration changes in the application pool properties which necessitate a restart of the processes.

I've checked machine.config & web.config and they don't show any modifications. Could it be a virus-scanner causing this? How do I find out for sure?

Comment: Does the AV have verbose mode logging that you can use to match up against the restart event?

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be triggered by a virus scanner.  I've seen this happen at several large corporate clients I've worked with.  It is recommended to have the application's folders whitelisted/excluded from realtime scanning.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2015/12/03/application-pool-gets-recycled-due-to-anti-virus/